# Check existing md5sum exist in file - Shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, grep, md5sum

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
I have a list of md5 hashed text that stored in `a.txt` file. Now i will input a text, i will hash it and check if the result is in my file or not. I'm using `grep` to do it but the script just work for a static string.

My script file looks like

```
file="a.txt"
s1="81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055 -"
echo "s1: "$s1

s2=$(echo -n "1234" | md5sum)
echo "s2: "$s2


if grep -Fx "$s1" "$file"; then
        echo 's1 FOUND'
else
        echo 's1 NOT FOUND'
fi

if grep -Fx "$s2" "$file"; then
        echo 's2 FOUND'
else
        echo 's2 NOT FOUND'
fi
```

In the `a.txt` file, i have only 1 line:

```
81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055 -
```

As above script, you can see, i set the value of `s1` as a static string and the `s2` is result of hashed.

The output that i got:

```
s1: 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055 -
s2: 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055 -
81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055 -
s1 FOUND
s2 NOT FOUND
```

As i can see on the screen - `s1` and `s2` have same value. `s1` is found in file but not `s2`. I don't understand what's wrong here and how to fix.

Comment: My implementation of md5 (on FreeBSD) does not output the " -" when input is stdin. Are you sure it is there? What about white-space? You should use `echo "s2: <$s2>"`.

Comment: I'm sure the value of s2. The output as you suggest: s2: <81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055  ->

Comment: OK. What's the result when you add `if test "$s1" = "$s2"; then echo equal; else echo unequal; fi`?

Comment: You should also place `set -x` near the top to enable trace mode in the shell.

Comment: As Cyrus said below, the my s2 string actually has 2 spaces before the minus sign when s1 has only 1. Your check by adding extra < and > showed the issue but i didn't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$s1` contains one space. Output of `echo -n "1234" | md5sum` contains two.

---

Replace

```
echo "s1: "$s1
echo "s2: "$s2
```

by

```
echo "s1: $s1"
echo "s2: $s2"
```

to see the problem.

---

Replace

```
s2=$(echo -n "1234" | md5sum)
```

by

```
s2=$(echo -n "1234" | md5sum | sed 's/  / /')
```

to fix this problem.